# Remove all instances of sub-string after a different sub-string has occurred N times

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I've been attempting to replace the character '-' with 'Z' but only if proceeded by 2 or more 'Z's in the string.

```
input = c("XX-XXZZXX-XZXXXXX", "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX", "XXXXXZXXXZXXZX-X", 
"XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX", "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX", "XX-XXX-ZZX", "XXZX-XXZXXX-XZ", 
"XZXZXX-XXZXXZXX")

desired_output = c("XX-XXZZXXZXZXXXXX", "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX", "XXXXXZXXXZXXZXZX", 
"XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX", "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX", "XX-XXX-ZZX", "XXZX-XXZXXXZXZ", 
"XZXZXXZXXZXXZXX")
```

I've had some success in removing everything before or after the second occurrence but can't quite make the gap to replace the needed character while keeping everything else. There's no grantee that either a Z or - will be in the string.

Comment: Please share your failed attempt. Also, I do not understand the requirement and the example: in `XX-XXZZXX-XZXXXXX`, the second `-` is not followed by 2 or more `Z`, why should it be `XX-XXZZXXZXZXXXXX`? Did you mean *must be preceded*? 2 or more `Z` must appear *before* the `-` in the string?

Comment: @stribizhev yes I was asking for a way to remove all "-"s after at least two Z's had appeared in the string. Your answer does this and has an elegant explanation. I have marked it correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an easy regex, but you still can use it to achieve what you need.

```
input = c("XX-XXZZXX-XZXXXXX", "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX", "XXXXXZXXXZXXZX-X", 
"XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX", "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX", "XX-XXX-ZZX", "XXZX-XXZXXX-XZ", 
"XZXZXX-XXZXXZXX")
gsub("(?:^([^Z]*Z){2}|(?!^)\\G)[^-]*\\K-", "Z", input, perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YCi0n5)

The regex just matches two chunks ending with `Z` (to make sure there are two `Z`s from the beginning), thenany characters but a hyphen and a hyphen. Only the hyphen is replaced with `gsub` because we omit what we matched with the `\K` operator. We match all subsequent hyphens due to `\G` operator that matches the location after the previous successful match.

*Explanation*:

- `(?:^([^Z]*Z){2}|(?!^)\\G)` - match 2 alternatives:

  - `^([^Z]*Z){2}` - start of string (`^`) followed by 2 occurrences (`{2}`) of substrings that contain 0 or more characters other than `Z` (`[^Z]*`) followed by `Z` or...
  - `(?!^)\\G` - end of the previous successful match
- `[^-]*\\K` - match 0 or more characters other than `-` 0 or more times and omit the whole matched text with `\K`
- `-` - a literal hyphen that will be replaced with `Z`.

**The `perl=T` is required here**.

Answer (score 1):

Way out of my league in regex here as demonstrated by @stribizhev's answer, but you can do this without regular expressions by simply splitting the entire string, counting up the occurrences of `Z`, and subbing out subsequent `-`:

```
input = c("XX-XXZZXX-XZXXXXX", "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX", "XXXXXZXXXZXXZX-X", 
          "XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX", "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX", "XX-XXX-ZZX", "XXZX-XXZXXX-XZ", 
          "XZXZXX-XXZXXZXX")

desired_output = c("XX-XXZZXXZXZXXXXX", "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX", "XXXXXZXXXZXXZXZX", 
                   "XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX", "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX", "XX-XXX-ZZX", "XXZX-XXZXXXZXZ", 
                   "XZXZXXZXXZXXZXX")


sp <- strsplit(input, '')
f <- function(x, n = 2) {
  x[x == '-' & (cumsum(x == 'Z') >= n)] <- 'Z'
  paste0(x, collapse = '')
}
identical(res <- sapply(sp, f), desired_output)
# [1] TRUE

cbind(input, res, desired_output)
#      input               res                 desired_output     
# [1,] "XX-XXZZXX-XZXXXXX" "XX-XXZZXXZXZXXXXX" "XX-XXZZXXZXZXXXXX"
# [2,] "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX"   "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX"   "XX-XXXZXXZXZXXX"  
# [3,] "XXXXXZXXXZXXZX-X"  "XXXXXZXXXZXXZXZX"  "XXXXXZXXXZXXZXZX" 
# [4,] "XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX"   "XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX"   "XXXZXXXZXZXZXXX"  
# [5,] "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX"   "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX"   "XZXXX-XXXZXZXXX"  
# [6,] "XX-XXX-ZZX"        "XX-XXX-ZZX"        "XX-XXX-ZZX"       
# [7,] "XXZX-XXZXXX-XZ"    "XXZX-XXZXXXZXZ"    "XXZX-XXZXXXZXZ"   
# [8,] "XZXZXX-XXZXXZXX"   "XZXZXXZXXZXXZXX"   "XZXZXXZXXZXXZXX"
```